# I am using Devise for Confirm email id's and for login. Is there any possibility to login directly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, email, devise, sms

I am using the devise for registration, login and confirm email, and here Devise is taking care of everything. Now if i click on link on email devise authenticating my email and now i am able to login.And i am sending small code to mobiles through sms. And my question is there any possibility to authenticate using that code and give the access to login to that particular user.I want to give both access to the user.like email and phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember Devise doesn't provide this functionality out of the box. But this is what you can do:

1. Add SMS confirmation code generator to your
   `app/controllers/confirmations_controller.rb` (class
   ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController) `create`
   method;
2. Modify confirmation email in your
   `app/views/devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb` to
   include SMS confirmation code and instructions how to use it;
3. Add SMS confirmation page to your application;

Answer (score 0):

If you want to authenticate using two fields for example say using email and phone_code
ovverride

```
find_for_database_authentication
```

method in devise model like this

```
def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
  conditions = warden_conditions.dup
  login = conditions.delete(:login)
  where(conditions).where(["phone_code = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { value: login.strip.downcase }]).first
end
```

Override the devise views, and replace

```
<%= f.text_field :email %>
```

with

```
<%= f.text_field :login %>
```

Using this, one can login with either email and phone_no.

But in this case also you must confirm email first.

you can skip email confirmation by removing `confirmable` module inclusion from devise model which is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. That is fine. But my question is i need to validate this email through email or by sms through phone. If he enter code on my page and click submit we are going to give access like same as when he click on email. for example i am not able to see my mail now soo now i can enter code what i get on my mobile in that case wee need to allow him to login like devise. got it